# Printing (saving) the last bash input command

Tags: bash, prompt

How can I get the last executed command from bash? I know that !!:p prints the last command, but it seems I can't use that anywhere except the bash prompt. I tried `echo !!:p` but it prints

```
~/Downloads$ pwd
Downloads
~/Downloads$ echo !!:p
echo pwd
```

I want to use this inside the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable so I need to get it as a string so I can just print it out. Is there an easy way to do this? Am I looking in the wrong place?

I guess I'm not clear. I need to store the last command run so I can re-display it after the output and before the next prompt. For example this is what I want the output to look like:

```
~/Downloads$ pwd
Downloads

pwd
~/Downloads$
```

I'm doing this my changing my prompt in my `.bashrc` file

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -en "\033[38;5;2m"!!:p"\033[0m\n"'
PS1='\W\$'
```

But !!:p only works correctly from the bash prompt. So how can I store the last command so that I can reprint it later?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'Printing(saving)'.  Where do you want the command saved to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the just-executed command line with the `history` built-in. (I have no idea why `history 1` prints the just-executed command line but `fc -nl -1` prints the previous commmand, as does `fc -nl 0`.)

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -en "\033[38;5;2m"; history 1; echo -en "\033[0m\n"'
```

This prints a number before the command text. Here's a version that removes the number. (It may be incorrect if you go beyond 99999 history lines, I don't know how bash formats the number then.)

```
prompt_function () {
  local prompt_history="$(history 1)"
  prompt_history=${prompt_history:7}
  echo -En $'\033[38;5;2m'"$prompt_history"$'\033[0m\n'
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_function
```

(Note that `echo -en ..."$prompt_history"...` would expand backslashes in the command line, so I use `echo -E` and let the shell expansion generate the control characters with `$''`.).

Comment: Cool, thanks. I can't say I understand 100% of why exactly that works, but it does =]

Comment: the `$'\033[38;5;2m'` and `$'\033[0m\n'` parts are ANSI escape codes.  The first one colors the contents of `$prompt_history` and the second resets the color to your terminals default.

Comment: I guess I should have clarified. What exactly is the reason for having to store `prompt_history` twice? Why does it need first the `$()` and then the `{:7}`?  I think it has to do with executing the command every time instead of caching, but what are the rules on that? Is that why it's written how it is?

Comment: @Falmarri: `history 1` prints a number before the command. As far as I know you can't directly perform string manipulation like `${:7}` on the result of a command substitution in bash, hence the temporary variable. See my revised answer.

Comment: Sorry one more question. I'm not an expert in bash (yet), can you quickly explain the quotes in your echo? For example why is the first $ outside the quotes, and why is the ascii control character in single quotes?

Comment: @Falmarri: `$'foo'` is like `'foo'` except that bash itself (and not the `echo` built-in) expands backslash escapes.